# What is the best way to download data from Wordpress acting as an CMS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, wordpress, content-management-system

will like to know if there are any plugins for iOS to download and sync data from Wordpress which will act as an CMS. data to be downloaded from wordpress are Video, Sound and text data.

i don't have any experiences on wordpress, will like to learn more from it.

thanks for reading and appreciated you comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing an iOS app, XML RPC is what you looking for.

http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support

Answer (score 1):

The WordPress iOS app is Open Source, don't know if that helps

[Source Code](http://ios.trac.wordpress.org/browser)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick iOS Wordpress starter kit I put together which outlines some basics when getting started with Wordpress and iPhone development.

https://github.com/davestitz/XMLRPC-Starter-Kit-for-iOS-Wordpress

You will also want to look at the Open Source Wordpress app that was also referred to below but it can be a little advanced and feature rich at first when you are just trying to understand the basics.

Comment: hi stitz, i tried out your starter kit...got this error
2012-01-25 15:39:14.493 XmlRpcStarterKit[6024:f803] -[NSURLError object]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68504a0
2012-01-25 15:39:14.495 XmlRpcStarterKit[6024:f803] getBlogsForUrl failed: -[NSURLError object]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68504a0
2012-01-25 15:39:14.495 XmlRpcStarterKit[6024:f803] Bad login or password

Comment: i changed URL,username & password